# Paso de una funcion recursiva a su forma cerrada en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Estoy trabajando con haskell para definir funciones de forma recursiva y cerradas. En este momento necesito pasar de la forma recursiva a la cerrada.
Tengo la función "intersección" a la cual le paso dos conjuntos y me devuelve el conjunto intersección definido de esta siguiente forma:

```
interseccion:: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a 
interseccion = \l1 l2 -> case l1 of{ [] -> [];
                                     x:xs -> case pertenece x l2 of { True -> x:(interseccion xs (filter (x/=) l2));
                                                                      False -> (interseccion xs l2)}
                         }
```

¿Cómo puedo escribirlo cerrado (sin usar case)?
Algunas funciones de listas que me pueden servir por ejemplo son:
remDups(que recibe una lista y elimina elems repetidos), pertenece (se fija si un elem pertenece a la lista), incluido (se fija que una lista A pertenezca a otra B), iguales (se fija que dos listas sean iguales), length (devuelve el largo de una lista), filter(se le pasa un predicado y una lista, y devuelve los elementos para los cuales el predicado es verdadero) y map (que aplica una funcion a todos los elementos de la lista)

Answer (score 0):

En `haskell`, casi se puede asegurar que sobran los *cases* y los *if/else*.

Al definir la función, puedes usar patrones que coincidan con los argumentos esperados:

```hs
interseccion:: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a 
interseccion [] _ = []
interseccion (x:xs) ys | pertenece x ys = x : interseccion xs (filter (x/=) ys)
                       | otherwise = interseccion xs ys
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocía esa forma de escribir en Haskell, ahora aprenderé sobre ella. Muchas gracias!